# Какой аналог оператора "and" из Delphi в C#?

Tags: c#, delphi

Пытаюсь разобраться в коде на Delphi:

```
var
  r: byte;
  rbuf: array[0..1024] of Byte;
begin
  ...
  r := rbuf[3] and 1;
  ...
end
```

Подскажите, какой оператор выполняет те же действия что и оператор "And" но в C#.

Comment: Очевидно, оператор `&`.

Comment: Кстати, у вас в коде странный буфер длиной в 1025 байт.

Comment: Ну, почему странный. Нулевой байт, бывает, нужен для чего-нибудь, чётность, критерий, принадлежность и т.п.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov: Вы забыли саму частую причину: просто забыли вычесть единицу, и это приводит к очень странным багам.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два вида `and`:

1. [Логический оператор](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Boolean_Operators): в этом случае операнды должны быть типа `boolean`
2. [Битовый оператор](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Logical_.28Bitwise.29_Operators): в этом случае операнды должны быть типа `integer`

---

В C# для каждого случая используется свой оператор:

1. [Условный оператор И](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator): `&&`
2. [Логический оператор И](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator): `&`

---

Так как в вопросе в качестве операндов используются целые числа, аналогичным кодом в C# будет: `rbuf[3] & 1;`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, что ты имеешь ввиду под _условным_ в данном случае? То что он и с bool Работает или что?

Comment: Не, ничего не имею ввиду. Просто ответ не понятен. *для каждого случая используется свой оператор:* — что это значит? Предполагается что после двоеточия перечисляются случаи и что в них используется, но это не так...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это была аналогия с delphi, где у оператора and может быть разное применение в зависимости от типа операндов, в отличие от этого у C# как будет происходить вычисление определяется оператором, а не типами операндов

Comment: Ну дык типами операндов тоже определяется же (в C#), если у нас операнды типа `bool`, то `&` будет как булево `И`, а не как побитовое

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не совсем, в чем отличие булевого И от побитового применительно к типу bool?

Comment: Побитовый не применяется к `bool`, потому что в `bool` нету битов никаких (про машинное представление речи не идет)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81686/discussion-between-grundy-and--nop).

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `&` в C# выполняет те же действия что и оператор `and` в Delphi.